# Redirect URL to custom URL through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, permalinks

I've got a page www.mypage.com and I want to redirect specific URL to another URL that does not exist.

For example, I want `www.mypage.com/about` to redirect to `www.mypage.com/about-company.php` , where /about does not exists - it's a custom URL written by me.

I've got no dynamic URL, only want to tell through `.htaccess` "this /CUSTOM_URL redirect to this /URL.php".

In the **URL bar, it must show the custom url**.

I don't know if it can be done. I've looked for it and all I've found are ways to rewrite dynamic URL and so, with patterns.

An example of that, would be the *Permalinks of Wordpress*, where you can specify which URL you want for each page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site to get the specific example you requested to work: to access `www.mypage.com/about-company.php` by using `www.mypage.com/about`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if about was requested, server about-company.php
RewriteRule ^about$ about-company.php [L,NC]
```

If you wanted a more general rule e.g. `www.mypage.com/anything` is used to access 
`www.mypage.com/anything.php`  you could replace the rule above with

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Or you could have all requests to to a single .php file that decides what page to display e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In fact, it seems that the server I am using has some troubles because what I tried before posting the question here, worked on another server. However, your solution worked perfectly. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for rewrite rules.

Some reading on that: [Apache Rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: I had read this before. It seems this server has some troubles because what I tried before, now works on another server, but not on this one. Thanks anyway for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Building on Ulrich Palha's comment, I found that this worked for me as an .htaccess file to provide alternative redirects with masking to a couple of my own .php pages:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(optionOne$|optionOneWithEndingSlash/$|optionTwo$|etCetera/$) ppl/peaceseeker.php [L] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(donny$|donny/$|donnycallahan$|donnycallahan/$) ppl/donnycallahan.php [L] [NC]
```

(I mention this because Ulrich's solution caused a problem for me when people typed example.com/about/ (with an ending slash)).

Thanks, Ulrich. If anyone knows how to modify Ulrich's .php-suffix Rule to descend recursively into any number of directories, I'd appreciate a comment!

As a temporary solution for anyone who needs to descend into directories, this worked for me:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ $1.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ $1/$2.php [L,NC]
```

The second command will handle the first subdirectory of all directories in the root folder of your website.

You can handle 3 levels of subdirectories, or 4, or 5, or 10, by just adding more instances of "/(\w+)" before the $ (one per new level of subdirectories), and then adding /$3, /$3/$4, /$3/$4/$5, or whatever is necessary immediately before ".php" in the Rule. I only needed 2 levels of directories (for now), so I'm good with what I posted; that solution is simple enough.

I'd still like a recursive solution if possible.