# 301 htaccess redirect for old urls to new urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to move all the URLs with this structure

```
domain.com/public/index.php/site/samepagename
```

to

```
domain.com/site/samepagename
```

can anyone help me with the `.htaccess`

this is not duplicate of my previous issue. This is new.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect URL to custom URL through .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382686/redirect-url-to-custom-url-through-htaccess)

Comment: its not same.. That was for my woocommerce wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create .htaccess file and and add the below lines:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^public/index.php/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ site/$1
```

OR

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^public/index.php/samepagename(.*)$ http://domain.com/site/samepagename$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Please note that above is not tested. Please test it locally before you deployed to production environment.

Comment: not working ..also i have updated the actual urls...there was a directory missing in old urls

Comment: does your server support mod_rewrite?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error

Also this is a laravel website so i have two htaccess one in public folder and one in public_html folder...

One more thing the url end like this
mydomain.com/site/mypagename.com or .net or .xys etc etc